# Unable to upload to ESP32 LOLIN D32 board

Tags: esp32

I'm not able to upload a sketch to this board with the Arduino IDE. This is the error during upload:

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 10), Board: "WEMOS LOLIN32, 80MHz, Default, 512000

Build options changed, rebuilding all
Archiving built core (caching) in: C:\Users\Karanbir\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_cache_223140\core\core_espressif_esp32_lolin32_FlashFreq_80,PartitionScheme_default,UploadSpeed_512000_6da8d55d0c53c0ebef21ae478b9e06ba.a
Sketch uses 178072 bytes (13%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 13880 bytes (4%) of dynamic memory, leaving 313800 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
C:\Users\Karanbir\Documents\Arduino\hardware\espressif\esp32/tools/esptool/esptool.exe --chip esp32 --port COM3 --baud 512000 --before default_reset --after hard_reset write_flash -z --flash_mode dio --flash_freq 80m --flash_size detect 0xe000 C:\Users\Karanbir\Documents\Arduino\hardware\espressif\esp32/tools/partitions/boot_app0.bin 0x1000 C:\Users\Karanbir\Documents\Arduino\hardware\espressif\esp32/tools/sdk/bin/bootloader_dio_80m.bin 0x10000 C:\Users\Karanbir\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_547051/Test.ino.bin 0x8000 C:\Users\Karanbir\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_547051/Test.ino.partitions.bin 
esptool.py v2.3.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "esptool.py", line 2637, in <module>
  File "esptool.py", line 2630, in _main
  File "esptool.py", line 2355, in main
  File "esptool.py", line 193, in __init__
  File "site-packages\serial\__init__.py", line 88, in serial_for_url
  File "site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 62, in open
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')
Failed to execute script esptool
the selected serial port Failed to execute script esptool
 does not exist or your board is not connected

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

This is displayed on the Arduino IDE's Serial Monitor on pressing the reboot button on the board:

```
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57

rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0018,len:4
load:0x3fff001c,len:4436
load:0x40078000,len:0
load:0x40078000,len:11816
entry 0x4007a9fc
[0;32mI (358) cpu_start: Pro cpu up.[0m
[0;32mI (358) cpu_start: Single core mode[0m
[0;32mI (359) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:[0m
[0;32mI (362) heap_init: At 3FFAE6E0 len 00001920 (6 KiB): DRAM[0m
[0;32mI (368) heap_init: At 3FFC4E70 len 0001B190 (108 KiB): DRAM[0m
[0;32mI (374) heap_init: At 3FFE0440 len 00003BC0 (14 KiB): D/IRAM[0m
[0;32mI (380) heap_init: At 3FFE4350 len 0001BCB0 (111 KiB): D/IRAM[0m
[0;32mI (387) heap_init: At 4008DE34 len 000121CC (72 KiB): IRAM[0m
[0;32mI (393) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user code[0m
[0;32mI (187) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on PRO CPU.[0m
OSError: [Errno 2] ENOENT
MicroPython v1.9.3-564-g9254f365 on 2018-04-26; ESP32 module with ESP32
Type "help()" for more information.
>>>
```

What can be wrong or needs correction?

Comment: you might have to connect gpio0 to gnd to flash it, many boards don't have that automated like most of the nodemcus

Comment: I will try this and update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with a USB cable of a length at 30cm
I took an other (10cm) and reduced the upload speed to 512000.
now it works